# GoogleChart not working in MVC

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, google-visualization

I want to create a Google chart with data from database.

I have an action which return a Json data, like this:

```
[{"Day":1,"Value":0.07,"Target":0.82},{"Day":2,"Value":1.00,"Target":0.82},{"Day":3,"Value":0.48,"Target":0.82},{"Day":4,"Value":0.63,"Target":0.82},{"Day":5,"Value":0.81,"Target":0.82},{"Day":6,"Value":0.18,"Target":0.82},{"Day":7,"Value":0.67,"Target":0.82},{"Day":8,"Value":0.70,"Target":0.82},{"Day":9,"Value":0.29,"Target":0.82},{"Day":10,"Value":0.47,"Target":0.82},{"Day":11,"Value":0.03,"Target":0.82},{"Day":12,"Value":0.67,"Target":0.82},{"Day":13,"Value":0.54,"Target":0.82},{"Day":14,"Value":0.32,"Target":0.82},{"Day":15,"Value":0.66,"Target":0.82},{"Day":16,"Value":0.22,"Target":0.82},{"Day":17,"Value":0.86,"Target":0.82},{"Day":18,"Value":0.53,"Target":0.82},{"Day":19,"Value":0.12,"Target":0.82},{"Day":20,"Value":0.48,"Target":0.82},{"Day":21,"Value":0.56,"Target":0.82},{"Day":22,"Value":0.32,"Target":0.82},{"Day":23,"Value":0.70,"Target":0.82},{"Day":24,"Value":0.48,"Target":0.82},{"Day":25,"Value":0.64,"Target":0.82},{"Day":26,"Value":0.20,"Target":0.82},{"Day":27,"Value":0.02,"Target":0.82},{"Day":28,"Value":0.24,"Target":0.82},{"Day":29,"Value":0.65,"Target":0.82}]
```

and I have this PartialView:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var chartData;
    google.load('visualization', '1.0', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

      $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetDataGoogleChart", "Charts")',
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json,chartset=utf-8",
            cache: false,
            success: function(data) {
                chartData = data.d;
            },
            error: function() {
                alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
            }
        }).done(function() {
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
            drawVisualization();
        });



    function drawVisualization() {

        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: 'Some Title',
            seriesType: 'bars',
            series: { 2: { type: 'line' } }

        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
    }
</script>



<div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
```

When I try to open this partial view I get this error message:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Can you help me make this chart?

**Edit**
My project structure is: _Layout > MainPage > PartialView with chart

the error is pointing me to MainPage - line 6 (when I click it, It show me the line 6 of the _layout - " `<meta charset="UTF-8" />`"

Comment: simple use of Amcharts `https://www.amcharts.com/demos/`

Comment: Documentation of google itself: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/drawing_charts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple things going on here.

First, the code posted in the question is mixing versions of Google Charts.

There are two script sources that can be used...

1) https://www.google.com/jsapi

Load statements looks like this...

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

2) https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js

Load statement looks like this, notice the secondary namespace `charts`...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

The latter, `loader.js`, is now the preferred method.

**ALSO**

As demonstrated in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35304392/5090771), using `setOnLoadCallback` in combination with `$(document).ready` can also cause issues.

To avoid, the callback function can be referenced directly within the load statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart'],
      'callback': drawVisualization
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your embedded script is executing before the external Google API is loading, try delaying execution by wrapping your script in...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
...
}
```

or, if you aren't using jQuery...

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
...
});
```

Comment: Hi Chris, I put all script content in $(document).ready(function(){...} still not working, I get the same error

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the Google API is being loaded? Check in Dev Tools > Sources

Comment: Please update your question with what line is throwing the error.

Answer (score 0):

There are a Two things going on here.

There are two script sources that can be used...

1) https://www.google.com/jsapi

Load statements looks like this:

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

2) https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js

Load statement looks like this, notice the secondary namespace charts...

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages': ['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);
```

(loader.js), is now the preferred method.

And as demonstrated in this SO post, using setOnLoadCallback in combination with $(document).ready can also cause issues.

The callback function can be referenced directly within the load statement.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.charts.load('current', {
      'packages': ['corechart'],
      'callback': drawVisualization
    });
});
```