# Multiple google charts issue in IE9

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Google multiple charts on the same page don't work in IE9. Works fine in FireFox.

I get error 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'gvjs_lK' is undefined'

Here is the example and code snippet. It is the same example given on google chart website.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/basic_multiple_charts

```js
      // Load Charts and the corechart package.
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});

      // Draw the pie chart for Sarah's pizza when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawSarahChart);

      // Draw the pie chart for the Anthony's pizza when Charts is loaded.
      google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawAnthonyChart);

      // Callback that draws the pie chart for Sarah's pizza.
      function drawSarahChart() {

        // Create the data table for Sarah's pizza.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 1],
          ['Onions', 1],
          ['Olives', 2],
          ['Zucchini', 2],
          ['Pepperoni', 1]
        ]);

        // Set options for Sarah's pie chart.
        var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Sarah Ate Last Night',
                       width:400,
                       height:300};

        // Instantiate and draw the chart for Sarah's pizza.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Sarah_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }

      // Callback that draws the pie chart for Anthony's pizza.
      function drawAnthonyChart() {

        // Create the data table for Anthony's pizza.
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
        data.addRows([
          ['Mushrooms', 2],
          ['Onions', 2],
          ['Olives', 2],
          ['Zucchini', 0],
          ['Pepperoni', 3]
        ]);

        // Set options for Anthony's pie chart.
        var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Anthony Ate Last Night',
                       width:400,
                       height:300};

        // Instantiate and draw the chart for Anthony's pizza.
        var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Anthony_chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
       <!--Table and divs that hold the pie charts-->
    <table class="columns">
      <tr>
        <td><div id="Sarah_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
        <td><div id="Anthony_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`setOnLoadCallback` should only be called once per page

but recommend adding `callback` to `load` statement instead

also, there have been some [recent issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39977130/5090771) using google charts in IE9

to avoid these issues, use google charts version `'44'` instead of `'current'`

see following working snippet...

```js
// Load Charts and the corechart package.
google.charts.load('44', {
  callback: function () {
    drawSarahChart();
    drawAnthonyChart();
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});

// Callback that draws the pie chart for Sarah's pizza.
function drawSarahChart() {

  // Create the data table for Sarah's pizza.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 1],
    ['Onions', 1],
    ['Olives', 2],
    ['Zucchini', 2],
    ['Pepperoni', 1]
  ]);

  // Set options for Sarah's pie chart.
  var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Sarah Ate Last Night',
                 width:400,
                 height:300};

  // Instantiate and draw the chart for Sarah's pizza.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Sarah_chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}

// Callback that draws the pie chart for Anthony's pizza.
function drawAnthonyChart() {

  // Create the data table for Anthony's pizza.
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Topping');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Slices');
  data.addRows([
    ['Mushrooms', 2],
    ['Onions', 2],
    ['Olives', 2],
    ['Zucchini', 0],
    ['Pepperoni', 3]
  ]);

  // Set options for Anthony's pie chart.
  var options = {title:'How Much Pizza Anthony Ate Last Night',
                 width:400,
                 height:300};

  // Instantiate and draw the chart for Anthony's pizza.
  var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('Anthony_chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<table class="columns">
  <tr>
    <td><div id="Sarah_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
    <td><div id="Anthony_chart_div" style="border: 1px solid #ccc"></div></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: getting error Microsoft JScript runtime error: Google Charts loader.js can only be loaded once.

Comment: do you have more than one load statement? check snippet above, works for me in IE9, and elsewhere...