# Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.LineChart

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization

Hi i'm getting `Uncaught TypeError: google.visualization.LineChart` in my console.

My code was working before today.

This is my full code of 2 google line chart:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Muli:400,400italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,400italic,700,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['line', 'corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart2);
    function drawChart() {
      var chartDiv = document.getElementById('chart_div');
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('datetime', 'Month');
      data.addColumn('number', "Total Donation Ratio");
      data.addColumn('number', "Total Trophies");
      data.addRows([
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 1, 45), 0.4815,  48592], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 15, 01), 0.4963,  48693], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 16, 02), 0.4963,  48711], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 16, 02), 0.4963, 48711]
]);
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'd MMM, yyyy, hh:mm a'});
formatter.format(data,0);   
      var classicOptions = {
      crosshair: { trigger: 'both' },
        title: 'Total Donation Ratio and Total Trophies',
        textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Muli'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontName: 'Muli'
        },
        height: 450,
        series: {
          0: { //Donation
            targetAxisIndex: 0,
            pointSize: 5,
            lineWidth: 5,
            curveType: 'function'
            },
          1: { //Trophies
          targetAxisIndex: 1,
          pointSize: 3,
          lineWidth: 4,
          curveType: 'function',
          color: '#b8860b'
          }
        },
        vAxes: {
          // Adds titles to each axis.
          0: {title: 'Donation Ratio'},
          1: {title: 'Trophies'}
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Timeline (GMT +8)',
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli'
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli',
                fontSize: 18,
                italic: false
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli'
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli',
                fontSize: 20,
                italic: true,
                bold: true
            }
        }
      };
      var classicChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv);
      classicChart.draw(data, classicOptions);
    }

    // CHART 2
    function drawChart2() {
      var chartDiv2 = document.getElementById('chart_div2');
      var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
      data.addColumn('datetime', 'Month');
      data.addColumn('number', "Troops Donated");
      data.addColumn({type: 'number', role:'annotation'});
      data.addRows([
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 16, 45), 73, 73], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 17, 15), 7, 7], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 18, 15), 60, 60], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 18, 45), 50, 50], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 20, 15), 56, 56], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 20, 45), 90, 90], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 21, 15), 20, 20], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 22, 15), 76, 76], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 22, 45), 10, 10], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 23, 15), 45, 45], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 27, 23, 45), 6, 6], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 1, 45), 61, 61], 
[new Date(2016, 1, 28, 15, 01), 652, 652], 


]);
var formatter = new google.visualization.DateFormat({pattern: 'd MMM, yyyy, hh:mm a'});
formatter.format(data,0);   
      var classicOptions = {
      //backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7',
      legend: { position: 'top', alignment: 'start' },
        title: 'Troops Donated in the Last 24 Hours',
        textStyle: {
            fontName: 'Muli'
        },
        titleTextStyle: {
            fontName: 'Muli'
        },
        height: 250,
        series: {
          0: {
            pointSize: 8,
            lineWidth: 3,
            curveType: 'function',
            color: '#001f3f'
            }
        },
        vAxes: {
          0: {title: 'Troops Donated'},
        },
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Timeline (GMT +8)',
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli'
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli',
                fontSize: 18,
                italic: false
            }
        },
        vAxis: {
        viewWindow: {
            min: [0]
            },
            textStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli'
            },
            titleTextStyle: {
                fontName: 'Muli',
                fontSize: 20,
                italic: true,
                bold: true
            }
        }
      };
      var classicChart2 = new google.visualization.LineChart(chartDiv2);
      classicChart2.draw(data, classicOptions);
    }

//]]> 
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_div2"></div>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
</body>
```

And here is my fiddler https://jsfiddle.net/4nsas23k/

I followed the examples from google charts documentation. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: This is popping up all over the place... it's caused by a release of a new version, and some conflicts with caching.  If you load a specific version number instead of just the latest it should work.  It's a temporary issue that should resolve itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out they had an update...

> It appears that when we push out a new version, there are some hiccups
>   in the system until the changes fully propagate. We will be working to
>   fix this in the future, but for now, if you get these kinds of errors,
>   I suggest you refresh the page, flushing your cache if necessary. You
>   can also change 'current' to '43' or '44' and it will work more
>   reliably.

Changing it to 44 `google.charts.load('44',` worked for me!

Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35661581/1700554